# ASP.NET MVC5 Identity issue with User.Identity.GetUserId() during login process

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-identity

I am using Asp.net Identity 2 in my application. I get the current user Id like this:

```
User.Identity.GetUserId()
```

It works fine, but when I login to my dashboard, and then create the user from dashboard like this:

```
User.Identity.GetUserId()
```

The id is replaced with inserted user.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Could you please include the code for creating the user in the question?

Comment: I used the default code of identity of register action of Account Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an implementation like the default `AccountController::Register`, note that this action signs in the new user after the registration, i.e.:

```
await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
```

You should be fine by removing that line in your implementation.